# Laravel getting same query with different conditions

Tags: php, laravel

I have query below:

```
$address = Address::where('id', $request->input('address_id'))->first();
$state = $address->state_id;

$mytime = Carbon::now();
$mytax = Tax::where('province_id', $state)
  ->where('validation', '=', 'active')
  ->where('valid_to', '>=', $mytime)
  ->first();
```

This simply check my taxes table and if expired date hasn't reached yet returns data. It's working perfectly **but the issue is that I have 2 conditions** and *this query only returns one of them*.

#### Conditions

1. Time based tax (query above)
2. Permanent tax which doesn't rely on dates (that part I don't have yet)

## Logic

1. Find tax based on `province_id` (first part of my query)
2. If no.1 passed, check `validation` column if is set to `active`
   means is time based and needs `->where('valid_to', '>=', $mytime)`
   part if is set to `inactive` it's not time based and always should
   return the data (in case there is any in database)

**Any idea how can I check `validation` column value before actually go for date validation?**

Comment: what is type of column `valid_to` in DB ?

Comment: @MateeGojra `dateTime`

Comment: i think instead of using multiple checks you should use some type of `JOIN(probably LEFT JOIN)`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the validation field may take two values. 'active' or 'inactive'.

This query will check two things. If the 'validation' is 'inactive' **or** the 'valid_to' is greater than today.

```
$mytax = Tax::where('province_id', $state)
            ->where(function($query) use ($mytime)) {
                   $query->where('validation', 'inactive')
                         ->orwhere('valid_to', '>=', $mytime);
                   })
            ->first();
```

Comment: You got part of it right but made mistake as well, see i want to validate `valid_to` column **only if** `validation` is equal to `active` otherwise i don't need to `valid_to` at all

Comment: Can a validation field have any value other than active or inactive? If the validation is inactive then it should be sent. Otherwise we should check the valid_to field.

Comment: Then the query should produce desired result. Let me explain. all inactive validation should be sent . Otherwise (i.e. if validation is active) then we compare with valid_to field. As it is an 'orwhere' operation we don't need to check whether the validation is active before checking with the 'valid_to' field.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to do.  But, based on the logic you presented, I don't think the problem is a query issue, but rather an architecture tweak -- you said it yourself, you have two different conditions.  And, I think you have two different queries; one is for *one* active record (`->first()`), the other is for *all* inactive records (`->get()`).

You can still just run one DB pull, but I think you need to separate out the logic into a conditional statement on that single DB pull:

```
$taxes = Tax::where('province_id', $state)->get();
```

Now that you have the taxes for that state, run the query on the collection to see if you need to pull the invalids:

```
$myTax = $taxes->where('validation', '=', 'active')
         ->where('valid_to', '>=', $mytime)
         ->first();
```

Then the conditional based on your original need:

```
if(!isset($myTax)){
    $myTax(es?) = $taxes->where('validation', '=', 'inactive);
```

This gives you potentially more than one, so you'll have to handle the difference between `first()` and a collection, but this would be one way to solve it.

Comment: so what if we use `findOrFail` instead of get in order to avoid more than one result? would that be good? let say: `$mytax = Tax::findOrFail($state);` and the run if conditions to see what is the value of `validation` column and get result by `first()` in there?

Comment: Not sure as I don't know what your primary key is - but I assumed there might be many taxes in that province.  If so, the findOrFail isn't what you want.  I think if you use the conditional on the single pull, and then add some line to handle the mulitple results (in the !isset($myTax) you now know you have multiple - pull the first or oldest perhaps), you can solve this using the above.

Comment: ok, i'll try your way see what will be the result and let you know later. thanks